# How to find the row - 2 field match 2 condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below
How to find the row -  field match a = 1 and d = 1 just like id:3 and id:5?

select * from table ... ?

Thanks

```
 id a b c d  

 1  1 0 0 0  
 2  0 0 0 0  
 3  1 0 0 1  
 4  0 0 0 1  
 5  1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write SQL statements, you can specify the selection condition using `WHERE` clause.  `WHERE` clause supports logical operators, including `AND` and `OR` and parentheses to group these.

In your very simple case, you'll have two conditions with logical `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a = 1 AND d = 1
```

Have a look at the [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) documentation and pay particular attention to the `WHERE` clause description.  Follow the corresponding links if required.

Comment: should i use 'select * from table where id =(select * from table where a = x and b= y)' or just 'select * from table where a=x and b=y'  if i try to echo that row's any field like 'row[id] row[a] row[..]'

Comment: @vibskov you don't need any sub-selects - it's a simple select statement, as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 1 AND d = 1
```